# View not found error after deploying Laravel app on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

App works fine on local server but on heroku it gives following error

```
 InvalidArgumentException:
   View [index] not found.
```

Route is set as:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

index.blade.php also exists in views folder

I have tried following:

1. Removed cache files from storage/framework/views
2. php artisan view:clear
3. php artisan route:cache
4. php artisan config:cache
5. php artisan key:generate

Any help please?

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Ossama Abd  the error is InvalidArgumentException:  View [index] not found.

Comment: What is the filename for the view? did you check that the casing is correct? "Index.blade.php" would work locally, but not on the server.

Answer (score 1):

you already done `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan config:clear`

Did you name your view correctly as `yourview.blade.php?`

Did you place the view correctly in `resources\views`

Comment: Yes views are named correctly and in correct folders since they're working fine on local host

Comment: @aliencity if they work locally, they can still be named wrong. check the casing.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself time clearing caches by writing this one command any time you're having doubts:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well.

Comment: Is your view inside another folder by any chance? Let's say your index view is in `views/users/index`, then the index would not be found without typing `return view('users.index');`

I know you already said it works perfectly on your local machine but I can't help but feel like something could've changed.